# How do I delete the Chrome App Launcher?

Tags: macos, dock

I'm running OSX 10.8.5 and I can't figure out how to get rid of the Chrome App Launcher.

In launchpad when I long click on it and things begin to wiggle there's no X for me to click to delete it.  I've also tried dragging it to the trash but that doesn't work.  I've used Finder to look through my applications and I can't find it there to delete it either.

I want it gone :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go to `/Users/YOUR_HOME_FOLDER/Applications` and delete the folder `Chrome Apps`.

Comment: this did not work on my macbook, it was NOT in the applications folder. This youtube video showed me how and no this in not a scam.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQwjGqR34ZU

Comment: Specifically, you only have to delete "Chrome App Launcher", not the entire "Chrome Apps" folder.  This is good for those who want to keep say Hangouts, etc., but don't want the App Launcher itself.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `~/Applications` and delete Chrome Apps.

Maybe you need use this command to remove Lauchpad icons:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db
defaults delete com.apple.dock
launchctl stop com.apple.Dock.agent
```

Answer (score 0):

easier is to

1) disconnect this device in google Dashboard ## allows for sync to enable launcher on other devices

2) chrome://settings  ## here you look toward the bottom and disable chrome app launcher  # reloading chrome is needed

3) re-check for chrome app launcher in Launchpad ## should no longer be there

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to delete it in another forum. You have to go to "home" then "applications" you will then see the folder "chrome app launcher" drag that to the trash bin and empty it!

Answer (score 0):

Once inside ~/Applications then run the following command:

rm -rf Chromium\ Apps.localized/